# Ожидание в ходе выполнения скрипта

Tags: windows, vbscript

Каким образом возможно "поставить" паузу в ходе выполнения кода скрипта VBScript? Мне необходимо, дабы между действиями, что выполняет скрипт, был временной промежуток в три секунды. Что-то наподобие возможности `Sleep(x)` в C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать, вот так:

```
WScript.Sleep X
```

где X время в миллисекундах.
[Возможно это тоже будет полезно](http://www.script-coding.com/WSH/WScript.html)

Comment: Это же первый ответ гугла, может в нём что-то не так?